# Drag and Drop keyword doesn't seem to work in Selenium2Library?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Drag and drop  ${source}  ${destination}

In the logs it's getting passed but in reality it's not doing dragged and dropped

Comment: I once had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855266/robotframework-selenium2library-why-does-drag-and-drop-not-work-with-draggabl).

Comment: Can you please give me a solution !!